# How to transpose a subset of values in a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm not sure if I am wording this correctly but I'll show it with an example.

I have tried "groupby" and "pivot" but I haven't been able to work it out.

So, this is my dataframe:

```
         col1       col2      col3
0         A          a         3
1         A          b         5
2         A          c         10
3         B          d         12
4         B          e         6
5         C          f         9
```

And the desired output would be:

```
        col2_1     col2_2     col2_3     col3_1    col3_2    col3_3
A         a          b          c          3          5        10
B         d          e         NaN         12         6        NaN
C         f         NaN        NaN         9         NaN       NaN
```

So far, I have tried to use for's:

```
frecs = pd.crosstab(index = frame['col1'], columns = 'frecuencia')
output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = 'col1')
for k in frame.index.values:
    for i in frame.keys():
        for j in range(1,frecs.frecuencia.values[list(np.unique(frame['col1'].values)).index(frame.loc[k,'col1'])]+1):
           output_df.loc[k,"".join([i,str(j)])] = frame.loc[str(int(list(np.unique(frame['col1'].values)).index(frame.loc[k,'col1']))+j-1),i]
```

Which, is close to it but falls short when assigning the correct element to each entry. I have also been looking to use groupby as in

```
frame.groupby(['col1']).apply(frame[list).apply(pd.Series)
```

but have found no luck either.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far exactly. Please share the snippets of code you used

Comment: Thank you @ScipioneSarlo. Well, the best I have so far is what I think is rather inefficient but at least is something. I'll update the question.

Comment: Can you describe in words what the output says and what is your method to get the output?

Comment: @HarvIpan Hey! Well, I would like to group-by 'col1' for each "category" of elements. Then, create n sub-columns for which the elements are the corresponding value of the category of the column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `set_index`, `groupby`, and `cumcount`:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['col1',df.groupby('col1').cumcount() + 1]).unstack()
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
df_out
```

Output:

```
     col2_1 col2_2 col2_3  col3_1  col3_2  col3_3
col1                                             
A         a      b      c     3.0     5.0    10.0
B         d      e    NaN    12.0     6.0     NaN
C         f    NaN    NaN     9.0     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Super close! you had the code:

```
a = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)

b = df.groupby('col1')['col3'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)

pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
```